# How to get the text value in the html form ? text value is used to proceed to next page

Tags: html, forms, text

I have a HTML form and on that I have to enter a text value on validating the text value the next page will be loaded

here is the code below describing my problem

```
<form action="http://abcd.com/sample/new/1" method="POST">
                    <p>
         <input type="text" name="**answer**" onkeyup="valid(this)" onblur="valid(this)"/>
                    </p>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="check"  /></p>
                </form>
```

I need the text value for "answer" so that it proceeds to next page say example "http://abcd.com/sample/new/2"

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to do this:

```
$("#YOURTEXTBOX").val();
```

Remember you have to put an id for your textbox for it to work.
Then you can use if statement to do the validation on client side.
You can also use server side code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are expecting,
Looks like a small html validation.
You can use javascript for validation.

Here is small example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if you need anything more thatn this...

try this : [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validation)